# Flutter search Spotify Song and save deep link

Tags: api, flutter, dart, spotify

Inside my app I would like to be able to search for a Spotify-Song and on selection, the deep link should be saved. By clicking on that link again, the user should be redirected to the Spotify-App or Web, if the App is not installed. I understand that there is this [Flutter Spotify SDK](https://pub.dev/packages/spotify_sdk), but I am quite new to Flutter and the documentation is quite confusing and I couldn't find what I need..

I am happy for every help! Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to provide you with a purely technical answer but I can show you how I would proceed if I were in your place:

First of all, if you don't want to use the SDK, you could rely on the APIs provided by Spotify ([here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/)).

From the flutter application, to call the APIs, you can use a simple http calling library ([here](https://pub.dev/packages/http)).

Once you have searched for a song through the API, I would try to save the deep link locally, to do this you can limit yourself to the shared preferences or you can use a small SQLite db, there are many possible ways.
([SQLite package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would like use the Spotify SDK but I don’t know the „flow“ that I have to code. Any tips on that?